# Creating an Opaque / transparent gatsby-background-image

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-gagarin-bss0k?file=/src/pages/index.js

---

Using [gatsby-background-image](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-background-image/#styling--passed-through-styles), I want a transparent background image.

Inline styling does not work.
Assinging a class with the opacity I want does not work.

```js
import BackgroundImage from 'gatsby-background-image';
    ...

      <BackgroundImage
        fluid={data.placeholderImage.childImageSharp.fluid}
        Tag="section"
        role="img"
        className="bgImage"
        style={{ opacity: 0.03 }}
      >
        <SEO title="Home" />
        <h1>Hi people - Gatsby3</h1>
        <p>Welcome to your new Gatsby site.</p>
        <p>Now go build something great.</p>
        <div style={{ maxWidth: `300px`, marginBottom: `1.45rem` }} />
        <Link to="/page-2/">Go to page 2</Link> <br />
        <Link to="/using-typescript/">Go to "Using TypeScript"</Link>
      </BackgroundImage>
    ...
```

```css
    .bgImage{
        object-fit: 'contain';
        width: '100%';
        opacity: 0.03;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.03)
    }

    .bgImage::before{
        opacity: 0.03;
    }
```

Setting opacity to `!important` works, but then all the children of the background-image all also transparent. I only want the background image to be transparent.

[image]

```css
.bgImage{
            object-fit: 'contain';
            width: '100%';
            opacity: 0.03 !important;
            background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.03)
        }
```

I've tried assigning all the children of `.bgImage` to not be transparent, but it doesn't work, they're all still transparent.

```css
.bgImage * {
        opacity: 1 !important;
    }
```

---

I can only get the desired effect I want(of a transparent background with the rest of the site being normal) if I got into my html in the browser and edit a pseudoclass to be

```css
.bgImage.gbi--640152265-sAbmzRF46cBzS5AanAhNU8::before {
z-index: -100;
background-image: url('https://bss0k-44413.sse.codesandbox.io/static/6d91c86c0fde632ba4cd01062fd9ccfa/630fb/gatsby-astronaut.png');
opacity: 0.03;
}
```

[image]

But how would I do this in code?

Comment: Can you please provide codesandbox link so can understand better .

Comment: @VyasArpit It's at the top of the question now, I can either make the background image with everything transparent, or else nothing is transparent. I want the background image to be transparent, but none of the content within

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opacity of the background image itself is set in the `:before` pseudoselector of your background container, so you will need to create a selector which include your background image container and accessing directly to you `:before`, of course, you'll need to use `!important` in that case... Something like:

```
.bgImage::before{
 opacity: .03 !important;
}
```

You can override completely the styles by replacing the `:after` pseudoselector too by:

```
.bgImage::after{
 opacity: .03 !important;
}
```

Comment: So that works until I switch to a different page. All my pages have the same background image, which is not opaque on any of the other ones, unless i refresh. I cleared my history and cache so i don't think that's it

Comment: Maybe then you can set a wrapper to that `.bgImage` and give them your desired opacity. I will update my answer.

Comment: The background image has children and a closing bracket, so I don't think you can wrap it

Comment: You can self-wrap a component but in this case, if you have content inside you're right.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, I modified this answer to be `.bgImage::before, .bgImage::after{
 opacity: .03 !important;
}` and it fixed my multi-page issue